# Paypal custom data

Tags: button, paypal

Is there a way to send custom data to Paypal when using a simple button to make payments?

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="D9DRKKKXPX5VL">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

I'd like to have field in this form where I can set a value and get it back with IPN. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can pass custom data through a button with this:

`<input name="custom" type="hidden" id="custom" value="stuff">`