# Correlated user with subscription button

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am using paypal subscription button. but i am facing a problem. when my site user click subscription button it redirected to paypal site. and after paypal it return to my set url. It is my generated code.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
```

My problem is  how i correlated this user to this subscription request. Is there is any option such that i can send my user's identity on paypal so that i can fetch information from paypal regarding this user.
Or any paykey so that we got information about this transection.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10014431/1671234  it is right answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your user ID for tracking users as the "item_number" or "custom" value. Both would be returned to in an IPN post and through PDT.

If you wanted to query PayPal about it you can do a GetTransactionDetails API call to look up a transaction ID and get the buyer information returned as well as the payment status.